# connection.connect() Takes too long when called for the first time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am trying to get the Bitmaps from multiple urls. I am using the following code.

```
Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src){

            try{

                URL url = new URL(src);
                Log.d(TAG, "bitmap url is : " + url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrl1: ");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrl2: ");
                connection.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrl3: ");
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrl4: ");

                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            }catch (Exception e){

                Log.e(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrlException " + e );
                return null;

            }

        }
```

but the `connection.connect()` takes too long to execute when called for the first time. I'm using this code in `AsyncTask` class.

Comment: What have you tried to prove the point _connection.connect() Takes too long when called for the first time_?

Comment: i have tried to run the above code for two urls one after another and the code runs faster for the second url. I confirmed that from the logs.

Comment: Okay so you mean the log: `Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrl3: ");` is coming a bit late in the 1st URL?

Comment: yes the log: Log.d(TAG, "getBitmapFromUrl3: "); is coming a bit late in the 1st URL.

Comment: Right!! can you provide both the urls pls

Comment: Does it depend on what the urls are?

Comment: Yes, Sometimes depending on the content of the URL, it does takes time.

Comment: I cant give you the url but i can tell that the urls download an image of size 26kb.

Comment: Okay, if the size of the url images is so small then I don't see a reason for the delay, have you tried Retrofit for the same? Try to use Glide library and see if it is being delayed

Comment: Glide library works fine. Thank you for your help @Ümañgßürmån